# Nodemon - app crashed - waiting for file changes before start

Tags: node.js

I am learning NodeJs on my own and I can not figure out what is wrong with my code. I am following a Youtube tutorial, seems I have the same code. I was also not able to install Nodemon globaly  `npm install-- nodemon` so I have done `npm install -g nodemon` instead. Error message:

```
MacBook-Pro-de-Pierre-Alexandre:untitled folder Pierre-Alexandre$ npm install -g nodemon
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules/nodemon/node_modules/graceful-fs
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules/nodemon
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules/nodemon/node_modules
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/nodemon/node_modules/graceful-fs
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! syscall access
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nodemon/node_modules/graceful-fs'
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nodemon/node_modules/graceful-fs']
npm ERR!   stack:
npm ERR!    'Error: EACCES: permission denied, access \'/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nodemon/node_modules/graceful-fs\'',
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'access',
npm ERR!   path:
npm ERR!    '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nodemon/node_modules/graceful-fs' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator (though this is not recommended).

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/Pierre-Alexandre/.npm/_logs/2019-08-10T22_44_05_357Z-debug.log
```

**APP.JS**

```
import express from "express";
import mysql from "mysql";


const db = mySQL.createConnection({
    host : "localhost",
    user : "root",
    password : "123456"
});



db.connect((err) => {
    if(err){
        console.log("bad!!!");
    }
    console.log("mySQL connected");
})




const app = express();


app.get("/createdb", (req, res) => {
    let sql = "CREATE DATABASE nodemySQL";
    db.query(sql, (err, resut) =>{
        if(err){
            console.log("data base creation failed");
        }
        res.send("database created...");

    });
});



app.listen("3000", () => {
    console.log("server started on port 3000 :D");
});
```

**PACKAGE.JSON**

```
    {
  "name": "tuto",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "mysql": "^2.17.1",
    "nodemon": "^1.19.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: You should post the error message you got...

Comment: I just did it, thank you

Answer (score 1):

The error tells you what is wrong -- the account under which you are running `npm i -g nodemon` doesn't have sufficient permissions to write to system files. This has nothing to do with your code.

Do `sudo npm i -g nodemon` instead.

Comment: As a side note, `nodemon` is a system-wide development tool. I politely suggest not including it as a dependency in `package.json`.

Answer (score -1):

Have tried? may help

npm i --save-dev nodemon

Comment: I recommend against rhetoric questions in answers. They risk being misunderstood as not an answer at all. You are trying to answer the question at the top of this page, aren't you? Otherwise please delete this post.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).